# Is it possible to understand the final topology if one understands the sum and quotient of spaces?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm going to make a not so specific question, since I don't know how to properly state it.

I'm having trouble understanding the final topology on some space $X$ with respect to a family of continuous functions $\{f_i:Y_i\to X\}_{i\in I}$. I believe I have a better understanding of the sum of spaces and of the quotient of spaces (as well, I think I understand better products and subspaces), so my question is: Is the space $X$ endowed with the final topology homeomorphic (or even better, equal) to some construction similar to a quotient of a sum, or a subspace of the quotient of a sum, etc? I think if this were the case, I could better understand how this topology works.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,

Given a family of continuous maps $f_\alpha: Y_\alpha \to X$, **if** $X = \bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha(Y_\alpha)$, then the topological space defined by the final topology on $X$ is a type of colimit:

$$
    X \cong \varinjlim_\alpha f_\alpha(Y_\alpha).
$$

It is well known that any finite colimit can be written as a coequalizer of a family of coproducts. That is to say, any such space $X$ is a quotient of sum spaces. The category-theoretic result is the formal dual of Theorem 1 of V.2 of MacLane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician*. Here's the outline:

Let $Y^\Sigma = \coprod_\alpha Y_\alpha$, and endow $Y^\Sigma$ with the sum topology. There are natural inclusion maps $\iota_\alpha: Y_\alpha \to Y^\Sigma$ coming from the fact that the underlying set of $Y^\Sigma$ is a disjoint union. Put an equivalence relation on $Y^\Sigma$:

$$
    \iota_\alpha(x) \sim \iota_\beta(y) \text{ in the case that } f_\alpha(x) = f_\beta(y).
$$

Then the quotient space $Y^\Sigma_{/\sim}$ is homeomorphic to $X$. Unfortunately, homeomorphism is the best you can get in the sense that the equivalence relation is defined in terms of the maps $f_\alpha$. This is because we do not generally assume that $X = \bigcup_\alpha f(Y_\alpha)$.

In the case that $X$ is not $\bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha(Y_\alpha)$, then there is a way to recover the "sums and quotients suffice" idea in your question using comma categories and more category theory, but that is considerably more complicated.

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting! I need to take some time to properly understand your answer, but thank you a lot!!

Comment: hi Anthony; +1, and I've taken the liberty of correcting a small typo in your post (namely adding the appropriate subscripts to $f$). hopefully that's alright! :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom that is alright! Thank you for catching that

Comment: The category language is certainly interesting, but if I understand you correctly then you are saying that the final topology with respect to a system of functions is the final topology with respect to the (one) induced map from the sum of the spaces, and the final topology with respect to a surjective function is canonically homeomorphic to a quotient.

Comment: @CarstenS that is correct, the sum topology on a disjoint union is the final topology, and the quotient topology on a quotient set is the final topology.

Comment: Hello once again! A certain idea came to my mind, which I think, if true, could help better understand the final topolgy. Since in the general case, we do not assume $X=\bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha(Y_\alpha)$, I was thinking of how the points in $X$ outside of the union could look like. Using the definition, i could see that if $x\in X\setminus (\bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha(Y_\alpha)) $, then for each $\alpha$, $f_\alpha^{-1}(\{x\})=\varnothing$, so $\{x\}$ is open. This would prove that any final topology could be seen as a disjoint union of a discrete space and the quotient of a sum. Is this correct?

Comment: @BryanCastro that is correct. Furthermore, by gathering all the points which are not in the union and calling that discrete space $U$, we see that we can define a new map $f_U: U \to X$ such that now $X = \bigcup_{\alpha} f_\alpha(Y_\alpha) \cup f_U(U)$, so the stipulation in my answer is not too strong in the big picture.